# Invalid prop `selected` of type `String` supplied to `Calendar`, expected instance of `Date`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, datepicker

I am using date picker In react js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker
but my current value is blank `null` .Now I want to show date picker when I focus to `input field` .but I am getting error/warning this why ?

```
proxyConsole.js:72 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `selected` of type `String` supplied to `Calendar`, expected instance of `Date`.
    in Calendar (created by OnClickOutside(Calendar))
    in OnClickOutside(Calendar) (created by DatePicker)
    in div (created by InnerPopper)
    in InnerPopper (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Popper (created by PopperComponent)
    in Manager (created by PopperComponent)
    in PopperComponent (created by DatePicker)
    in DatePicker (created by Main)
```

Actually I added one condition while transforming the data

```
 data[i].displaytext = i;
        if (data[i].dataType === "DATE" && data[i].value) {
          data[i].value = new Date(data[i].value);
        }
        obj[lastLabel] = [...obj[lastLabel], data[i]];
      }
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/rmx02zzr5o

Please help me to remove this warning

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the default `value` in your `DOB` object is a string, but the component you're passing it to is expecting a `Date`. It looks like changing

```
DOB: {
    value: "",
    type: "FIELD",
    editable: true,
    dataType: "DATE",
    required: true,
    displayName: null,
    pattern: null
}
```

to

```
DOB: {
    value: null, // <- specifically this line
    type: "FIELD",
    editable: true,
    dataType: "DATE",
    required: true,
    displayName: null,
    pattern: null
}
```

will least make the error go away and the date picker work, at least insofar as it sets the value in the text field.